# Download entire drupal contrib repository

Tags: version-control

I would love to download (or, preferably, clone via git) the entire drupal contrib repository (6 for now, but 7 also). That way I can do cool stuff like search the repository via grep for hooks, examples, and implementations that I can reflect upon, improve, copy or steal. Is this possible? Is there a native way to do this via drupal.org or github.com/drupal? Do *you* have a current-ish copy of said repository. Please. Don't be greedy.

Comment: You can find all Drupal modules here: http://ftp.drupal.org/files/projects/

Comment: @Mohammad Ali Akbari - is it possible to download the entire projects directory?

Comment: Simply you can download all links with internet download manager (IDM) or other downloading tools

Answer (score 5):

http://drupal.org/sandbox/greggles/1481160

> This project provides one way to help solve the issue Provide a way to download the entire git codebase for all projects.

Comment: Freaking brilliant.